# How to find out whether there is leap year between a date range?

Tags: formula-field

Could anyone please advise how to find out between a date range if there is leap year or not.

e.g `Start Date = 1 Jan 2019` and `End Date is 31 Dec 2022`

now using f`ormula field` or `Apex` , how to check if there is a leap year is present or not between a date range.

Comment: For what purpose do you need this information? How are you going to use the resulting number? I am asking just in case the bigger question can be answered instead.

Comment: We are basically calculating Term between Start Date and End Date and formula we are using is (EndDate - StartDate)+1)/ (365/12) ,  but when a leap year comes in between we need to do (EndDate - StartDate ))/ (365/12) , thats why wanted to check how to calculate leap year between two date range